# Call JavaScript function from remote server

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I tried to call JavaScript function exist on some server(server1) from another server(server2) and I got this error:

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://server1/ from frame with URL https://server2/ . Domains, protocols and ports must match.

I used JSP, Java, JavaScript and tomcat7, is there any way to solve this problem? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you only need some data from the other server, there is ajax for that.

Comment: You're trying to call a JS function inside of an iframe? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: why dont you include the .js file from the remote server into the servlet of your server?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, must add a cross-origin rule to the header of your javascript file, which allows access from your other server.

Otherwise, your Browser doesn´t let you do that.

You can look at the answer of this Question: [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

It should tell you how to do it.

Comment: thanks for answer, I tried to put this in the header
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"); but it didn't solve the problem.
how can I add it? do you have any useful links please.

Comment: This only works for enabling CORS (cross domain resource sharing) - not for enabling cross domain access between windows.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net) - it provides an RPC feature allowing you to call methods across the [Same Origin Policy](http://www.google.no/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy&ei=LH2ITe-KINCSswa2q9m7DA&usg=AFQjCNHVFZYpkC1JSDNgda021fYJ8pRuDQ).

Take a look at one of the demo's [here](http://consumer.easyxdm.net/current/example/methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

As described you are subject to the Same Origin Policy, this is designed to protect users.
Google have a good write-up: http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2.

There are several typical approaches to working around this:

1. jquery has a getJson or jsonp type of function. most other js libs have something similar. They use a dynamic Script tag, suitable for GET requests from other domains.
2. Create a servlet on domain1 that proxies to domain2 - allows unrestricted HTTP methods and use of XmlHTTPRequest.

I've not tried http://easyxdm.net/wp/

There are improvements coming, like cross document messaging in [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/postmsg/)